# How to broaden bars in chart in BIRT

Tags: charts, birt

I make this simple report with chart in BIRT:
[image: chart1]
but when I added grouping on Y axis, then bar became very tight and unevenly distributed.
How can I make this bar bigger ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve your issue :

1. Edit your chart,
2. then go in the format chart,
3. click on Chart Area
4. on the bottom, click on the "General properties"
5. a pop-up named General Properties is open.

Change the Unit Spacing (0 is for 100% - I suggest you 10)
 1. Then click on Apply 
 2. and click on Finish

See : 
[image: General Properties]

Comment: Thanks for reply, problem is that this option doesn't work when grouping on y axis is enabled. When I type 10 or 1 unit space bar is thin as in screen.

Comment: I think, it's because you split "Zasoby" in 7. So, the column has been split in 7...

Comment: So, is there posibility to have grouping on y axis and normal width bar ? What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party but I was having this exact issue and tried to fix it by changing the Unit Spacing only with no luck. So here's what I did in case someone stumbles upon this question like me:

I followed the same steps and changed unit spacing to 25 (but any number closer to 0 will help)

Then I removed the "Optional Y Grouping" here 
[Data set definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4UWi.png)

And defined the Series Grouping instead in the "Color By" -> "Categories"
[Series Grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAlz7.png)

I'm not a BIRT expert but this approach serves the same purpose for me and actually allowed me to change the width